# Exercise 11.29 Tom M. Apostol Mathematical Analysis: $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ \cos(ax)}{ b^2 +x^2}\, dx= \frac{ \pi}{2b} e^{-|a| b}$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Consider the following problem:

> Prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ \cos(ax)}{ b^2 +x^2}\, dx= \frac{ \pi}{2b} e^{-|a| b}$.

I am not able to solve it but it seems that 11.27 (a) will be used which I have proved.

11.27 (a): If $f$ satisfies the hypothesis of Fourier integral theorem then show that if $f$ is even, i.e. $f(-t)= f(t)$ for every $t$, then show that $$\frac{ f(x+) + f(x-) } {2} = \frac{2}{\pi} \lim_{ \alpha \to \infty}  \int_{0}^{\alpha} \cos (vx) \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} f(u) \sin (vu)\, du \right)\, dv .$$

Can you please help me using this result in the given question?

Comment: There's no need to YELL!

Comment: See Pag. 71- Messenger of mathematics volume: 2 by unknown author London [u.a.]; 1873 and Messenger of mathematics
volume: 5
by unknown author
London [u.a.]; 1876

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me study three cases

- If $a=0$, then
  $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{b^{2}+x^{2}}dx \underbrace{=}_{y=\frac{x}{b}} \frac{1}{b} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+y^{2}}dy=\frac{1}{b}\arctan(y)|_{0}^{\infty}=\frac{\pi}{2b}.$$
- Now assume that $a>0$. We integrate $f(z)=\frac{e^{iaz}}{b^{2}+z^{2}}$ over the following contour

[image]

Note that $f$ only has one simple pole inside this figure, which is the point $z=ib$. Thus, the Residue Theorem implies
\begin{equation} \tag{1} \int_{\gamma \cup C} fdz=2 \pi i\mathrm{Res}[f,ib]. \end{equation}
We compute the residue:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Res}[f,ib]=\lim_{z \to ib} (z-ib)f(z)=\lim_{z \to ib} \frac{e^{iaz}}{z+bi}=\frac{e^{-ab}}{2bi}.
\end{align*}
Thus, the RHS of (1) is equal to $\frac{\pi}{b}e^{-ab}.$ Now we deal with the LHS. First, note that by triangle inequality $R^{2}-b^{2}\leq |z^{2}+b^{2}|$. Also, $|e^{iaz}|\leq 1$ for $z$ with $\mathrm{Im}(z)>0$. So, by the [$ML$-estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma)
\begin{align*}
\left|  \int_{C} fdz \right| &\leq \pi R \sup_{z \in C}|f(z)| \\
& = \pi R \sup_{z \in C} \frac{|e^{iaz}|}{|b^{2}+z^{2}|} \\
& \leq \pi R\frac{1}{R^{2}-b^{2}}.
\end{align*}
This says that $$\left| \int_{C}fdz\right| \xrightarrow{R \to \infty} 0.$$
Also,
$$ \int_{\gamma}fdz=\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{e^{iax}}{b^{2}+x^{2}}dx=\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{\cos(ax)}{b^{2}+x^{2}}dx+i\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{\sin(ax)}{b^{2}+x^{2}}dx.$$
This implies that
$$ \int_{\gamma}fdz \xrightarrow{R \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{b^{2}+x^{2}}dx+i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{b^{2}+x^{2}}dx.$$
Therefore, if we let $R \to \infty$ in (1), we conclude
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{b^{2}+x^{2}}dx+i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{b^{2}+x^{2}}dx=\frac{\pi}{b}e^{-ab}.$$
Taking the real part of this expression we obtain
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{b^{2}+x^{2}}dx=\frac{\pi}{b}e^{-ab}.$$
Finally, using that $g(x)=\frac{\cos(ax)}{b^{2}+x^{2}}$ is an even function, we conclude that
$$2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{b^{2}+x^{2}}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{b^{2}+x^{2}}dx=\frac{\pi}{b}e^{-ab},$$
that is,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{b^{2}+x^{2}}dx=\frac{\pi}{2b}e^{-ab}.$$

- The case when $a<0$ is similar to the previous one. You only have to change the contour by a semicircle in the negative semiplane and consider $-ib$ as a residue instead of $ib$.

Answer (score 0):

A well-known integral is proposed. Let us try to get the answer without hints.

- Let us get
  $$I_1(b,x) = \int\limits_0^\infty e^{\large-xt+ibt}\,dt = \dfrac{1}{x-bi} = \dfrac{x+bi}{x^2+b^2},$$
  $$\int\limits_0^\infty e^{\large -xt}\sin(bt)\,\text dt = \dfrac b{x^2+b^2},\quad
  \int\limits_0^\infty e^{\large -xt}\cos(bt)\,\text dt =\dfrac x{x^2+b^2},\tag1$$
  $$I = \dfrac1b\int\limits_0^\infty\int\limits_0^\infty e^{\large -xt} \cos(ax)\sin(bt)\,dt\,dx
  = \dfrac1{|b|}\int\limits_0^\infty\int\limits_0^\infty e^{\large -xt} \cos(|a|x)\,\sin(|b|t)\,dt\,dx.\tag2$$
- Substitutions
  $$x=|b|y,\quad t=|a|z,\quad p=|ab|\tag3$$
  provide the scaling in the form of
  $$I = \dfrac1{|b|}J(p),\tag4$$
  where
  $$J(p)=p\int\limits_0^\infty\int\limits_0^\infty e^{\large -pyz}\cos(py) \sin (p z)\,dz\,dy = \int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac {\cos(py)\,\text dy}{y^2+1} 
  = \int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac {z\sin(pz)\,\text dz}{z^2+1}.$$
- Since
  $$J(0)=\int\limits_0^\infty\,\dfrac{\text dy}{y^2+1} = \dfrac\pi2,\quad
  J'(p)=-\int\limits_0^\infty\,\dfrac{y\sin(py)\,\text dy}{y^2+1} = -J(p),\tag5$$
  then from the trivial ODE
  $$J(p)=\dfrac\pi2 e^{\large -p},$$
  $$\color{green}{\mathbf{I = \dfrac1{|b|} e^{\large -|ab|}.}}\tag6$$